# Tornado ioloop instance seems to be shared across processes

Tags: python, tornado, ioloop

In a multiprocessing application, a main process spawns multiple sub processes. Each process is meant to run its own Tornado ioloop. However, I noticed that when the process is started, all the instances of `IOLoop.current()` (in main and all the sub processes) are the same. Wouldn't that mean that `ioloop.spawn_callback(my_func)` runs all in one ioloop context (in the main process)?

Here's a minimal example that I could extract:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def sub(i):
  print('sub %d: %s' % (i, hex(id(IOLoop.current(True)))))
  for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)


def main():
  print('main  ', hex(id(IOLoop.current(True))))

  for i in range(2):
    sub_process = Process(target=sub, args=(i, ))
    sub_process.daemon = True
    sub_process.start()

  time.sleep(5)

main()
```

Output:

```
main   0x7f14a09cf750
sub 0: 0x7f14a09cf750
sub 1: 0x7f14a09cf750
```

Are the processes created correctly and isn't the expected behaviour that there would be multiple ioloop instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned in Tornado's [docs](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html#processes-and-ports)

> it is important that nothing touches the global IOLoop instance (even indirectly) before the fork

You can get the behavior you want using a slightly modified `main` function:

```py
def main():
    processes = []
    for i in range(2):
        process = Process(target=sub, args=(i,))
        process.daemon = True
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)
    print('main  ', hex(id(IOLoop.current(True))))
    time.sleep(5)
```

Output:

```
main   0x7fbd4ca0da30
sub 0: 0x7fbd4ca0db50
sub 1: 0x7fbd4ca0dc40
```

## Edit

As for the explanation: the sharing is due to due to how `fork` is implemented in Linux: using `COW` (copy-on-write); this means that unless you **write** to the shared object in the child process, both parent and child will share the same object. As soon as the child modifies the shared object it will be **copied** and **changed** (these changes won't be visible in the parent).

Comment: The pertinent difference between our snippets is that in your's the access to `IOLoop.current()` occurs after the creation of the sub processes. What I don't understand is how an object reference can be shared like this across processes and why it's done. It's actually quite difficult to do that, so I guess it's intended behaviour (but why?). Other than the docs (your link) exemplify, I don't want to share the IOLoop (in the example network ports are shared which may require some synchronisation effort, I guess). This is all a bit magic to me, so I guess I'm missing something here...

Comment: Is the edited explanation regarding COW satisfactory?

Comment: I didn't see the edit - thanks. Does this mean that `IOLoop.current().add_handler(...)` in the child process would constitute a **write** which copies the object and thus these event loops will be absolutely separate?

Comment: Yes, but you should test it. On another note, the `hex(id(object))` testing methodology for separate processes is not correct because objects having the same ID in their process do not necessarily represent the same object. So for checking you would need find another method (perhaps checking the IOLoop's `handlers` dict if you are using `add_handler`).